# If someone spent some money from amanat (trust)?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, money

Suppose a person, have amanat (money) of another person. Now, what is the islamic ruling regarding "if he/she spent some money from it, considering if the one whose amanat he/she has, asks for that, he/she will pay him/her in complete". So, can he/she spent money from another ones amanat and when he gets gets money from say salary and will put that money back into that amanat.

Comment: You obviously have to get permission from the person. You can’t just use someone else’s money and then let them know. Unless you know of some Hadith or Islamic tradition that states otherwise about trusts.

Answer (score 1):

> عن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال‏:‏ ‏ "‏ إن
> الدين يسر، ولن يشاد الدين إلا غلبه، فسددوا وقاربوا وأبشروا، واستعينوا
> بالغدوة والروحة وشيء من الدلجة‏"‏ ‏(‏‏(‏رواه البخاري‏)‏‏)‏‏.‏
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "The religion (of Islam) is easy

This is the Sheikh of Islam his opinion about amanat :

> Ibn Taymiyah said: "Borrowing money from amanat , if you know the
> owner of the money is satisfied in his heart.There is nothing wrong
> with that, and this is only allowed to happen when a man who has experienced him
> through life .If you know he will not accept the action, it is not allowed".

According to Ibn Taymiyah  there is nothing wrong with it if that person accepts it. If not so, it is either one of these two things  (Haram if you take the money, you can not return it back or Makruh if you can).

والله اعلم

[read](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/307783)

Answer (score -1):

You are given the money to safe keep the money. If you really in need of money, you should get permission from the owner of the money before you spend from it. Otherwise it wouldn't be **SAFE** keeping, cause it is not safe from you too